# Veracrypt, what is the purpose of the small EFI partition, beyond the boot manager?

Tags: encryption, disk-image, disk-encryption, veracrypt

I have Veracrypt full disk encryption under windows. I have 100MB partition which appears to store the EFI software and a 450mb windows recovery partition.

Does this EFI partition and its software do anything else.

Specifically, does it contain any keys needed for decryption or configuration information about the encrypted partition?

I currently backup only my encrypted C drive and not the other partitions, on the basis that I think I only need the C drive because the other are generic.

Comment: "Does this EFI partition and its software do anything else." - Yes, you are able to boot to your OS because of this partition.  Without this partition you would be unable to boot to your OS.  **DO NOT DELETE THIS PARTITION.**  Your backup, without this partition, is useless.  Based on the fact, you have an EFI partition, means you are using Veracrypts extermental GPT support.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. What I mean is, should I have a hdd failure, will I need the EFI partition that matches the encrypted C drive. As I am only keeping a backup image to the C drive partition.

Comment: You need all your partitions, otherwise, its very unlikely you copied the Veracrypt header in your current backup.  Without the header, your data will be inaccessible, and decryption will not be possible.

Comment: OK, thats what I was afraid off.